# Replace Statement: String or binary data would be truncated - NVARCHAR(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a procedure that previously took the string from a stored procedure in my database and replaced certain tables and removed large chunks of the procedure via a long replace function. I would then create a new procedure using this manipulated string

It worked for about 2 months but recently I'm getting the error message

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
>   String or binary data would be truncated

I've tried altering the data types and also removing every single replace statement but it errors out on the first Replace Statement which makes me think its an issue with the datatypes or my initial manipulation.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @PriorityProcedureString AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @PriorityProcedureString = 
(SELECT 
     /*1*/REPLACE(
     /*1*/OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME)),
    (SUBSTRING (OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME)), -- String 
                CHARINDEX('µ',OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME))), -- Start_Position
                (CHARINDEX('!',OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME))) - CHARINDEX('µ',OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME))))-- Length
                )
    )   
                                                                                    ,''
                                                                                    )
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
            WHERE specific_name LIKE 'usp_Cs_Coll_NBA_Priority_And_Exclusions'
)

SELECT @PriorityProcedureString

-- EXEC @PriorityProcedureString
```

Comment: That query is just unreadable. Can you post something that illustrates the issue without it being so verbose?

Comment: The code & error has no any direct relation.

Comment: Are you getting an error running the code you posted? That seems very unlikely, given it's just a `SELECT`. Maybe when you execute a stored procedure created using this output of that replace chain, but there is no way for anyone but you to debug it, as it requires actually knowing the code, types of the columns in the tables, etc. What your question is right now sounds like "hey I have a car, I replaced parts, it no longer starts. Can you help?" without saying what kind of a car and parts you actually have.

Comment: This looks like it's dynamically building a query or command based on conditions. Please post the queries or outputs you expect this code to produce, and specify the conditions that should produce the respective output. There are likely better ways to get the output you need than a nested `REPLACE()`.

Comment: Hey, appreciate all the feedback given. I've simplified the code to one replace statement as the error occurs regardless of the number of nested replaces. In regard to the point of the statement I'm just looking to create a 'CREATE PROCEDURE AS' statement from an existing procedure script using the Information.Schema.Routines column that contains the procedure string. The output I expect is that it creates this new string that I can then execute. Forgot to mention I have an identical script that looks at another procedure that does not error in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the original question realize it wasn't very clear what the issue was. 
I wasn't able to identify the problem but suspect that the REPLACE function potentially has a limit of characters and once the first REPALCE was resolved it was potentially truncating my string before moving onto the next REPLACE?

Instead I've put it into a variable and done the replace statement in steps, this does not give me any errors.

The basic goal of this code was to just take an existing live procedure that populates business critical tables and replace all the tables in it with dummy or simulation tables so that I can mess around with different logic output results and not affect any lives processes. I wanted to do it this way because the procedure is altered by different SQL users on a daily basis so manually scripting it out would leave the 'Simulation' procedure out of date.

If anyone has a more efficient way of doing this appreciate if you could share as the below solution is cumbersome and requires manual updating whenever new tables are added.

```
/******************************************************************************************
    * Put Procedure Text Into String *
    *******************************************************************************************/

SET @Priority_ExecutableString = (
                       SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id(ROUTINE_NAME))
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
                       WHERE specific_name LIKE 'usp_Cs_Coll_NBA_Priority_And_Exclusions'
                       )

/******************************************************************************************
*   Use Substring To Remove Parts Of String *
* As defined by the µ start and ! End Points In The Original Procedure
*******************************************************************************************/

SET @StringIWantToRemove = 
(
SELECT SUBSTRING (@Priority_ExecutableString, -- String 
CHARINDEX('µ',@Priority_ExecutableString), -- Start_Position
(CHARINDEX('!',@Priority_ExecutableString) - CHARINDEX('µ',@Priority_ExecutableString)))-- Length
)



   SET @Priority_ExecutableString = (SELECT REPLACE(@Priority_ExecutableString, @StringIwantToRemove,''))

/**************************************************************************************

    ****
    *   Step 2 : Replace Defaulted 'Create Procedure' With 'Alter Procedure'
    *******************************************************************************************/

SET @Priority_ExecutableString = (SELECT REPLACE(@Priority_ExecutableString, 'Create Procedure', 'ALTER PROCEDURE'))

/******************************************************************************************
*   Step 3 : Replace Original Procedure Name With Simulation Procedure Name
*******************************************************************************************/

SET @Priority_ExecutableString = (SELECT REPLACE(@Priority_ExecutableString, '[dbo].[usp_Cs_Coll_NBA_Priority_And_Exclusions]','[dbo].[usp_Cs_Coll_NBA_Priority_And_Exclusions_Simulation]'))

/******************************************************************************************
*   Step 4 : Replace Offer_Stage Table With Offer_Stage Simulation Table
*******************************************************************************************/

SET @Priority_ExecutableString = (SELECT REPLACE(@Priority_ExecutableString, 'WORKDBOPS_NBA.dbo.t_CS_Coll_NBA_offer_stage','WORKDBOPS_NBA.dbo.t_CS_Coll_NBA_offer_stage_Simulation'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the length of some of your code is longer than 8,000 characters. CHARINDEX has an 8,000 character limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `expressionToFind` has a 8000 character limit but I don't spot them using that with a long string. I just see `'µ'` and `'!'`